# What hardware/firmware factors might be behind Windows XP taking several hours to boot up?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, troubleshooting

I have an old Dell Dimension 2400 desktop with Windows XP (circa 2003) that I use pretty much solely for playing old video games.  Unfortunately, though, lately it's become somewhat of a problem.  If I Hibernate it every time I'm done with it, it works okay, but if I accidentally turn it off instead of placing it in hibernate, the next time I try to power it on it sometimes takes many hours to boot up again, stuck at the Windows XP logo screen (with the progress bar).

My first thought was that it was a software problem.   Who wouldn't, right?  This is the original 13-year old installation of Windows XP, so it's highly likely that the Registry and probably other important stuff are a tangled spaghetti mass by now.  So I bought a new 250 GB hard drive, dropped it in (the previous hard drive was just 40 GB!!), and reinstalled from the DVD.

**Instead of solving the problem, it just got worse!**  My brand-new installation exhibited literally the *exact* same behavior, spending hours at the XP logo screen.  I left it overnight to see what would happen and the next day it still hadn't booted.  This is actually worse than the way it behaved with the old hard drive.

So this is almost certainly a hardware or firmware issue given that it appeared independent of the hard drive and Windows installation present.

### Any ideas as to how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable Boot Logging to check what is your Windows doing in the start up process, and that may clarify what is taking so much time.

To enable Boot Logging press F8 while starting, Windows Advanced Options, Enable Boot Logging.

More information in: [Windows Boot Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457123.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at whether or not it is a hardware issue, please include your specs with your post.  As a suggestion, if you are feeling that it is a hardware issue, I would get into the build itself and check things out if I were you